# jquery - submit after prevent default by on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

It works with get method and window location but I need to submit a form only with post method. Post method for delete something is more safe. So I need a submit method and call that specific form. How to do that?

html (Laravel):

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin-sdk/messages/delete/{{ $mes->id }}" class="genposts" data-postid="{{ $mes->id }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <button type="submit" class="fa fa-trash btn-sm btn-danger" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                </form>
```

jquery:

```
$('.genposts').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var postId = $(this).attr('data-postid');
        var texttitle = $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().text();

        $('#post-body').text(texttitle + ';');

        $('#edit-modal').modal();

        function deleted() {
          $(this).off('submit').submit();
          return true;
        }


        $('#modal-save').on('click', deleted());
    });
```

Comment: The first thing that is weird is you are binding a click event handler to a form object, rather than a submit event handler.  Aside from that, I'm still unclear on what your issue is.

Comment: I need when I clicked the "modal-save" button to submit the specific form.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you need to attach the `click` handler to `$("button[type='submit']")` and call `$(".genposts").submit()` inside that `click` handler.

Comment: If I do that: $('#modal-save').on('click', function(){
            $(this).off('submit').submit();
        }); it didn't respond because $(this) is referring to modal save which is outside of form.

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleted() {
    $(this).off('submit').submit();
    return true;
}

$('#modal-save').on('click', deleted());
```

So couple things with this. ---------^

See that () at the end of the deleted method?  That's making it execute.  When you create an event binding, it expects a function reference, not an execution.  So since you are executing the method what you are actually binding as a click handler is what is returned from that method, which is a boolean 'true', which is not valid.  Change it to:

```
$('#modal-save').on('click', deleted);
```

Next, the delete method.

```
$(this).off('submit').submit();
```

If '#modal-save' is a button inside a form, calling submit() on it doesn't make sense.  You want to submit the form for the button which would be either of the following:

```
$(this).trigger('click');
$(this).closest('form').submit();
```

One concern is that you are creating a binding to the modal-save inside the handler for the genposts click event, which can result in multiple bindings, which should be avoided if this is the case.

Comment: I just did the corrections and I haven't any response. Modal-save button is outside of the form.